How to collect on a state Farm Fire and Casualty surety bond for 300000
How to collect on a State Farm fire and Casualty Company surety bond

What does "collect" mean? You'll probably need to elaborate a bit.

What have you tried?

What is the context? Were you wronged by someone who provided you evidence of this bond? If you were contacted unsolicited it’s probably a scam.

You will probably have to sue the bonded individual. The bond just ensures that there is money you can collect if the lawsuit is successful.
